# What is the best way to show category by image?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I have a online store with commerce module .
I have a category/taxonomylike this :

Writing Product

- pen
- pencil

Art Product

- paper
- something

All i want is to show `writing product sub category` in a page with image.
i've added image field to taxonomy and create a views from taxonomy .

How can i get sub category (image field) from views ?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you view change the **Format** section to show fields and after that add the image field from your taxonomy, then add the filter `Taxonomy term: Parent term`

Comment: Thx , i don't want to show parent .

Comment: If you add the filter `Taxonomy term: Parent term` then it will show only the child terms.

Comment: thx a lot maaaan and how can i show it from specify parent not two of them ?  
How can i filter it ?

Comment: follow my previous comment and give the parent id equal to `id of Writing Product`

Comment: no , when i add equal , it only shows both parent

Comment: what filter you have added

Comment: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= product)
Taxonomy term: Parent term (= Writing Product)

Comment: did you give the **term id** of Writing Product

Comment: how can i get that ?
go to taxonomy page and put my cursor on edit and see the term id is : term/7

Comment: then the id is 7, use that

Comment: You're perfect and teach me something new .
Thx a million ;)